# How to check that I have recovered from Penguin 2.0?

Tags: penalty, google-penguin-algorithm

I have 3 year old website which has been hit by Penguin 2.0 in May. The website traffic dropped almost 30%. I have been working hard from last 2.5 months on the website and my website's traffic recovered in last week of August. In fact, I am receiving more traffic then ever.  When I look at the stats, I find my website's search engine visibility has been improved.  It is now appearing for more search queries. My website's impressions have also increased.

What I am worried about is that my website is nowhere in top 5 pages for keywords having high competition and carrying the highest search volume. They are few in number but important.

Should I consider my current situation as recovery or it's just the partial recovery? If it is only partial, then how come traffic is more then it was before penguin 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

That means, your link profile isn't strong enough yet to rank for those competitive terms. Check the DA of the competitors that are ranking and their On Page SEO to get better insights on why they rank. Further, you can do a link profiling and see which links are helping them rank. May be they have links from more relevant sources.

If you observe any upward movements for your existing keywords, it clearly indicates that you are no longer affected by Penguin.

Also, if you still have low quality links, then Google will reply back to your reconsideration request stating the fact that you still have some poor links. If you haven't received that message, it should mean you are out of danger.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well Google as always replies with the message that Sorry your website isn't manually penalized and now it does not even allows to submit the reconsideration.

Comment: Ok, that means there is no longer a manual penalty applied to your site. All you need is more link juice flowing to your site to outrank your  competitors for those head terms.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what [Jim Boykin has to say about Penguin recovery](http://www.seobook.com/jim-boykin-on-internet-marketing):

> ...if a site has 1000 domains that link to it, and 900 of those are artificial and I disavow them, there might not be much of a recovery depending on what that 100 links left are....ie, if I disavow all link text of "green widgets" that goes to your site, and you used to rank #1 for "green widgets" prior to being hit by a Penguin update, then I wouldn't expect to "recover" on the first page for that phrase..... where you recover seems to depend on "what do you have for natural links that are left after the disavow?"

Based on his experience, your site will never be exactly the same.  The links that you had with matching anchor text that were powering your rankings for those keywords are never going to do so again.  So while you get site-wide penalties lifted, you still don't rank for the terms that you had been targeting with exact anchor text matching links.

Comment: I understand that. That is why for 2.5 month I was creating new links against that disavow. I maintained diversity in these links which has ranked me for the other terms but not the old ones.